# How to wait for dot-sourced script to finish?

Tags: powershell, wait, pester

I'm writing a PowerShell script to run a Pester test.

```
. .\..\LoadModule.ps1
. .\..\..\SomethingElse\LoadModule.ps1

Import-Module Pester -MinimumVersion 4.0.0
Invoke-Pester -Script .\Test\
```

However Pester runs before output from the two dot-sourced scripts has finished, and I'm afraid that the modules they're supposed to load have not fully loaded which could lead to inaccurate test results.

The `ImportModule.ps1` scripts search for a specific .NET `.dll` and then `Import-Module` it.

I've tried putting an `&` in front of the `Invoke-Pester` command, but it didn't help.

So, how do I make PowerShell wait for the dot-sourced scripts before running Pester?

Comment: Dot sourcing isn't asynchronous -- it can't be, because the whole point is to make definitions available to the caller, which wouldn't work if it this process was asynchronous. The scripts and/or loaded modules might kick off threads or jobs that run asynchronously, but that's another matter. Output might appear "out of order" if it's not synchronized with PowerShell's streams, but that's also another matter. What reason do you have for believing "Pester runs before output from the scripts"?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I consistently see one of the two scripts output after Pester, it's module establishes a database connection which might be asynchronous.

Comment: If the modules are really doing asynchronous work, you're basically screwed without a mechanism to synchronize with them to signal when they can "start" or "are ready". Such code is poorly testable, and should be rewritten if possible. The obvious alternative is to defer the loading to the Pester tests themselves, so nothing can possibly happen before them. But before doing any of that, verify that the tests are really going wrong, and that you're not just seeing deferred/buffered output that doesn't actually reflect when things happened -- that's inconvenient at best, but not a dealbreaker.